# Converting SQL statement using SUM() to Linq/Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the following SQL statement to Entity Framework using Linq:

```
SELECT SUM(Column1) AS Correct
     , SUM(Column2) AS Incorrect
     , UserName
FROM   Stats 
WHERE (StatType = 0)
GROUP BY UserName
ORDER BY UserName
```

For the purposes of this question, all the column types in the DB are type INT, and there are multiple rows of data per user. I basically want 3 columns in my output, with the total of correct & incorrect selections for each user.

It seems like such a simple SQL statement but whatever I try in something like LinqPad, I always get errors. I must be missing something relatively simple. As soon as I start add a ".Sum" clause I get compilation errors etc.

```
Stats.Where(s => s.StatType == 0)
     .GroupBy(s => s.UserName)
     .Select(x => new {  Correct = x.Column1
                       , Incorrect = x.Column2
                       , User=x.UserName})
     .ToList()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
Stats.Where(s => s.StatType == 0)
     .GroupBy(s => s.UserName)
     .Select(x => new { Correct = x.Sum(y => y.Column1),
                        Incorrect = x.Sum(y => y.Column2),
                        User = x.Key})
     .ToList();
```

Please note that `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValues>>`.
That means that the `x` inside the `Select` is an `IGrouping<TKey, TValues>`.  That in turn is basically just an `IEnumerable<T>` that contains all rows of that group along with the key of this group.
So, to get the sum of all items in a group, you need to use `Sum` on the grouping and specify which columns to sum as a parameter to the `Sum` method.